# Javascript executing before CSS transition finishes

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have the following code that isnt working. It is supposed to Make a div that when clicked, moves up and fades away, then comes back down and reappears. However whenever I add the part to come back down and reappear, The second part executes before the the second part has a chance to transition. Any help to make it delay so that the div moves up and then comes down like I want it to? I've tried using a timer, but I dont think Ive been doing it right. Here's the code.

```
/*function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}*/
function clicked(x) {
    x.style.top="-50px";
    x.style.opacity="1";
    //sleep(500);
    //setTimeout(function(){alert('hi)}, 500);
    //x.innerHTML="女";
    x.style.top="50px";
    x.style.opacity="1";
}
```

Comment: I would try jquerys .after() if jquery is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the two motions and activate the second part with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

```js
var click = document.getElementById('click');
click.addEventListener('click', function() {
    slideUp(click);
    setTimeout(function() { slideDown(click); }, 500);
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqPwf/1/)

If you can use jQuery, you might employ [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp().delay(500).slideDown();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xh7QU/1/)